# Is there a way to install a list of extensions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I maintain a repository of ways to install all the extensions I need on any device for my editors -- this is fairly simple for Sublime, Atom, and Vim because they all have package managers which allow me to run a command to install a list of packages.

I looked through the VS Code Managing Extensions and it looks like there is a way to [share recommendations of extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions) in a file, but it sounds like that just populates the suggestions. I also know I can just manually call each extension one-by-one and call `code --install-extension [extension]` but that seems tedious (I could shell script it and make it go through my own list but was wondering if there was a better way).

Comment: See extension packs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-manifest#_extension-packs

Comment: @Mark Those are for creating extensions with internal dependencies, not for individual use.

Comment: @ifconfig : I went through the yeoman generator and it is super easy to create an extension pack - which is just one folder that can be installed into any `<user home>/.vscode/extensions` directory and work.  I think it is what @aug wants.  You don't have to create your own extension to use it other than the pack (which is easy).  You can even include all your current extensions with one click and you are basically done. The "Workspace Recommended Extensions" is pretty slick too.

Comment: @Mark Fair, I can now see how that would work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you are operating out of a workspace, you can use the "[Workspace Recommended Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions)" feature to emulate a similar behavior.

Create an `.vscode/extensions.json` file in the workspace folder and populate it with a list of extensions you want to include.

*i.e.*

```
{
    "recommendations": [
      "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
      "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint",
      "robertohuertasm.vscode-icons",
      "vscodevim.vim",
      "waderyan.nodejs-extension-pack"
    ]
}
```

This allows you to provide a list of extensions that will show up in the Extensions tab when the "Show Workspace Recommended Extensions" flag (`@recommended:workspace` in the search box) is checked.

[image]

This is certainly not as complete as having the feature you requested, but it is the closest thing that I know of in VS Code.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer since this is pretty much the closest thing. It's still useful to have for your development team if you want to have development environments aligned.

Comment: In the current version of VSCode this works a little more conveniently. If you have recommended extensions in `.vscode/extensions.json` you will see a prompt when you open your editor. This prompt will let you see or install recommended extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find the best way to do this and used a one-liner in Powershell to install the recommended extensions from extensions.json or a list of extensions.

> I'm using --force option to update the extensions if they're already installed

Install all recommended extensions from extensions.json:

```
(Get-Content -Path .\.vscode\extensions.json | ConvertFrom-Json).recommendations | Foreach -Process {code --install-extension $_ --force} | Select-String -Pattern "\[lua\]*" -NotMatch
```

To install a list of extensions:

```
<comma separated list of extensions> | Foreach-Object -Process {code --install-extension $_ --force } | Select-String -Pattern "\[lua\]*" -NotMatch
```

e.g.

```
"bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss", "ecmel.vscode-html-css", "davidanson.vscode-markdownlint", "bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles", "esbenp.prettier-vscode" | Foreach-Object -Process {code --install-extension $_ --force } | Select-String -Pattern "\[lua\]*" -NotMatch
```

> The "Select-String -Pattern "[lua]*" -NotMatch" bit is to filter out the warning message that vscode keeps printing